# Add title below the graph with four plots in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, title, r-grid

Due to the privacy of the data, I use `mtcar` dataset in `ggplot2` to explain my question.

There are four plots:

```
g1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,wt)) + geom_point()
g2 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_point()
g3 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,drat)) + geom_point()
g4 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,qsec)) + geom_point()
```

I want to put these four plots in one graph, so I use `grid.arrange()` function in package `grid.Extra`:

```
grid.arrange(g1,g2,g3,g4,ncol=2)
```

[image: raw graph]

And now, I want to add title below each plot in these graph, something like the picture below(I modified it in Word, so it isn't beautiful)
[image: modified pic]
Before asking, I have searched in `SO`, and I know how to add title below one plot, for example, use `grid.text()` or these three method    [Displaying text below the plot generated by ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014187/displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2) or `element_text(vjust=-10)`, but I can't apply it to four plots in one graph. Meanwhile, I have got some results in base graph [How to add a title to each plot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393911/how-to-add-a-title-to-each-plot-in-r) or [Common main title of a figure panel compiled with par(mfrow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660372/common-main-title-of-a-figure-panel-compiled-with-parmfrow), the qustion is that I want to conduct it in `ggplot2` and the title is below each plot, how do I implement it? Thank you!

Comment: Something along the lines of what Bob Rudis did? https://twitter.com/hrbrmstr/status/709069752879214592

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thank you, but the title is still on the top of plot, what Bob uses are title and subtitle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could wrap each plot with arrangeGrob first,

```
g1 <- g2 <- g3 <- g4 <- ggplot()
titles = LETTERS[1:4]
plots = mapply(arrangeGrob, list(g1,g2,g3,g4), 
               bottom = titles, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
grid.arrange(grobs = plots, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, you have solved this question excellently, but I still wonder why `ggplot` package doesn't have the method to add title below the graph directlly